# How do I limit invocations to my google cloudfunction using a google service account and oauth?

Tags: oauth, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function I want to call from a rails app that is currently running on Heroku. I have a service account set up for the rails app, and the could function is deployed and triggered by HTTP request. I want to limit invocations of the cloud function to the rails app, and was planning to use server-to-server 2-legged OAuth 2.0 following [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#jwt-auth) from google.

When I'm setting up the service account though, I need to supply a scope. According to the list of [available scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#cloudfunctionsv1) the only scope referring to Cloud Functions allows management of the cloud function, whereas I want a scope to cover invocation only.

The language used in the docs refers to scopes being used to define access to Google APIs.

- Does my cloud function qualify as a google API in this sense?
- Otherwise, since scopes are URLs, could I just supply the URL of my cloud function as a scope?

Comment: Is it an option for you to use API Key for your call?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, it's a possibility. But I want to know if I **can** get OAuth working as a mechanism of limiting cloud function invocations

Comment: Is the function is private? If so, do you use OAuth for being authenticated? If not, you use the JWT token to authenticate the user by yourself?

Comment: The function is private, and the plan is to use OAuth

Comment: If you use OAuth with service account, use the audience equal to your function root URL. And add the role cloudfunctions.invoker to the service account for allowing it to reach the function. More detail [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating)

Comment: Okay, this is why I'm asking here. Your link says self sign your JWT. The [example code](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_service_account) that page links to implies you need to sign it with the service account private key. Which is correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. But you haven't a service account, right?

Comment: Also, I'm still not clear on how to populate the scope in my JWT claim? Is scope mandatory? Can I just skip it?

Comment: I have got a service account specifically set up for my rails app, so I should use that service account's private key? If I've got the private key, what is the advantage of OAuth then, can't I just use the private key to generate a bear token directly?

Comment: Look at this doc: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#service-to-function

Comment: You have to generate a bearer token with your service account, just set correctly the target audience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, I managed to cobble the process together from several disparate Google documentation pages, namely

1. https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_service_account

   - incorrectly instructs you to self-sign your JWT, which obviously won't work because then anyone could sign their own JWT and access your cloud function
2. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#service-to-function

   - this example doesn't tell you what audiences to set in your initial JWT claim
3. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests

   - incorrectly describes the JWT claim contents and signing process
   - the [alternate method](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#jwt-auth) of using service account signed JWTs directly as bearer tokens doesn't work for calling cloud function, I'm guessing because they aren't google APIs

Here's what worked for me

1. Marshal a JWT with the following data. The main trick was to set `aud` to the OAuth endpoint, set `sub` to the service account's email (even though there's no user to impersonate), and `target_audience` to the Cloud Function's URL (per doc #1), but follow the general process in doc #3.

   ```
   {
     "aud": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
     "sub": "<your service account's email style identifier>",
     "iss": "<your service account's email style identifier>",
     "target_audience": "<the URL of the cloud function you're trying to call>",
     "exp": <unix epoch timestamp + 3600 as an integer>,
     "iat": <unix epoch timestamp as an integer>
   }
   ```
2. Base64 encode the claim. Base64 encode a claim header set (`{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}`) and combine the results with a period, `header.claim`, per generic instructions in doc #3. You should get something like this: `eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiI3NjEzMjY3OTgwNjkt...`. Contrary to doc #3, you don't need `kid` in the headers.
3. Use the service account private key to sign the JWT with your favourite JWT library
4. Exchange your service account signed JWT for an access token from Google's OAuth system, by making POST call to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` with an `Authorization: Bearer <signed JWT base64 encoded string>` and the following two fields form data encoded:

   - `grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer`
   - `assertion: <signed JWT base64 encoded string, YES you use it twice>`
5. If all goes well, you should receive a JSON response containing a key `id_token`, which you can use in an `Authorization: Bearer <id_token>` when you call your CloudFunction

Comment: You're a life saver ! The google documentation is really messed up sometimes !

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud Functions documentation regarding [this topic](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#service-to-function) covers several use cases:

> - Securing developer access so that only specific users can invoke the
>     function during testing.
> - Securing function-to-function access so that only authorized functions
>     can invoke your function.
> - Securing end-user access to an application from mobile or web clients.

Your use case is the third one, the end-user authentication is integrated through [Google Sign-In](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#google_sign-in) and [Firebase Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#firebase_authentication) but this won't be useful for restricting HTTP calls to allow only your Heroku App.

At this point the workaround should be managed by checking in your Cloud Functions code whether the request comes from the Heroku App and reject those which doesn't.

Comment: That documentation is wrong, at least for my case. Self-signed JWTs aren't accepted by the exchange endpoint. Also, the sample code implies this is a call to a Google API, and CloudFunctions aren't APIs

Comment: Hi sirlak, you are right this does not cover your use case. I'm editing my answer as your use case might have to be managed within the code of your Cloud Function.